# Handling variable-fonts when printing a webpage to PDF using Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, fonts, preview

I'm working on a webpage that has a different "print to PDF" result (after *Ctrl+P -> Save to PDF* in Chrome) than the original web display by using `@media print` in the CSS code.

I'm using a variable font with the parameter `font-variation-settings:"wght"`, but the generated PDF seems to ignore this parameter when used in `@media print`.
Yet, when using the Chrome tool *"Inspector>Rendering>Print emulate CSS media type"*, changes of this parameter are taken into account in the displayed web page!

Looks like the problem comes from the Ctrl+P interface, any ideas on how to handle this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1070089 - this should be fixed now, you may want to retest with a recent Chrome Canary build and see if the issue is indeed gone.